# Alternative of function 'parcluster' in older MATLAB versions (R2010b)?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

What is the alternative of function `parcluster` in MATLAB R2010b? I basically want to validate the 'local' cluster using command line, and searching for the R2010b version of below code which is for newer MATLAB versions.

```
cluster = parcluster();
job = createJob (cluster);
createTask(job, @sum, 1, {[1 1]});
submit(job);
wait(job);
out = fetchOutputs(job)
```

Comment: Does `createTask` exist in R2010b? If so the examples in `doc createTask` should contain an alternative.

Comment: Thanks so much, this was a great idea!

Answer (score 1):

So, I am answering my own question thanks to Daniel's comment. Here is the R2010b version of submitting a job to local scheduler from the command line:

```
cluster = findResource('scheduler','type','local');
j = createJob(cluster);
obj = createTask(j, @sum, 1, {[1,1]});
submit(j);
waitForState(j);
taskoutput = get(obj, 'OutputArguments');
```